# return subversion working copy to an old revision

Tags: svn, revision, revert, working-copy

I had some problems with my subversion server and i had to restore it from backup but it is an older one. 
For example i have the server at revision 400 but my working copy is at 405.
How can i get my working copy to an older revision withought loosing my work and recommit the changes.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How can i get my working copy to an older revision withought loosing my work - WTF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand, which I am **100% sure I don't**!

1. Make a copy of your working directory at 405
2. Checkout 400
3. Copy back (minus the .svn meta) files from 405 to 400 checkout
4. Commit 401.

*Thanks Dave* - To copy the working directory from 405 over your 400 commit:

```
[aiden@devbox ~]$ svn export --help
export: Create an unversioned copy of a tree.
```

Making sure you don't wipe-out 400's .svn directories. Make sure you got everything added with

```
[aiden@devbox ~/my400co]$ svn status
```

If you want the server back at 405 (but the new 405 :S) ... do some small commits and then a big dirty one at 404->405

I am presuming that your checkout copy contains the entire trunk and is a consistent trunk to recommit. Otherwise, you have data holes :)

Then **tell everyone else to update their code from the repo!** otherwise people might start making drunken commits!

Comment: @lc - I thought the redbull was distorting things :P Thanks!

Comment: To do the copy without .svn folders, you can use "svn export"

Comment: instead of having to copy manually you could use diff and patch